# Does $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum^{n^2}_{k=n}\frac{1}{k}$ exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

Does $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n^2}_{k=n}\frac{1}{k}$ exist?

**MY TRIAL** 
\begin{align} \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum^{n^2}_{k=n}\frac{1}{k}=\int^{n^2}_{n}\frac{1}{t} \,\mathrm{d}t=\ln n^2- \ln n=\ln n\end{align}

Please, am I right? If no, can anyone show me the right answer? Thanks!

Comment: That's not right.

Comment: @xbh: Wow, I'm wrong? But how?

Comment: Explain your first $=$. That does not make sense to me.

Comment: You are not right. Your first step is clever but wrong. The limit is asyntotically equal to thye intagral (as $n$ tends to infinity), but not exactly equal.

Comment: Your idea is correct but your statement is wrong. A) The limit,  a number independent of $n$, is not equal to a function of $n$. B) Your sum is not equal to the integral, but you can probably show the sum is larger than the integral (up to a small error).

Comment: @Kusma: I admit that my idea is wrong but kindly show me the right thing to do. Thanks!

Comment: wa says it tends to infinity  https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%2Fk+sum+from+k%3Dn+to+k%3Dn%5E2+,+limit+n+tends+to+infinity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo. 2 methods.

1. Using the asymptotic expression of harmonic series
   $$
   H_n = \sum_1^n \frac 1k = \log(n) + \gamma + e_n\quad [e_n \to 0 \text{ as } n \to \infty],
   $$
   where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant, we have
   $$
   \sum_n^{n^2} \frac 1k = H_{n^2} - H_{n-1} = 2\log(n) - \log(n-1) + e_{n^2} - e_{n-1} \geqslant \log(n-1) + e_{n^2} - e_{n-1},
   $$
   let $n \to \infty$, then the limit is $+\infty$.
2. Since $1/x$ is decreasing on $(0, +\infty)$, we have 
   $$
   \begin{split}
   \sum_n^{n^2} \frac 1k 
    &= \sum_n^{n^2} \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac 1k \mathrm d x \\
    &\geqslant \sum_n^{n^2} \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac 1x \mathrm d x \\
    &= \int_n^{n^2+1} \frac 1x \mathrm d x \\
    &= \log(n^2 +1) - \log(n) \\
    &> \log(n^2) - \log (n) \\
    &= \log (n) \to +\infty
   \end{split}
   $$
   hence the limit is $+\infty$.

Comment: Please, can you explain how \begin{align} \sum_n^{n^2} \int_{k}^{k+1}\frac 1x \mathrm d x = \int_n^{n^2+1} \frac 1x \mathrm d x ? \end{align}

Comment: $$
\sum_n^{n^2} \int_k^{k+1} f(x) \mathrm dx = \left(\int_n^{n+1} + \int_{n+1}^{n+2} + \cdots + \int_{n^2}^{n^2+1}\right) f(x) \mathrm dx = \int_n^{n^2+1} f(x) \mathrm dx,
$$ since integrals are additive w.r.t. the intervals.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you do not need integrals to prove that your limit is $+\infty$. By letting
$$ T_n = \sum_{k=n}^{n^2}\frac{1}{k} = \frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}\sum_{k=jn}^{(j+1)n-1}\frac{1}{k}$$
we have
$$ T_n \leq \frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}n\cdot\frac{1}{jn}=\frac{1}{n^2}+H_{n-1} $$
as well as
$$ T_n \geq \frac{1}{n^2}+\sum_{j=1}^{n-1}n\cdot\frac{1}{(j+1)n}=\frac{1}{n^2}-1+H_n$$
so you may draw the conclusion from the divergence of the harmonic series.
With integrals a correct approach is given by
$$ T_n = \int_{n}^{n^2+1}\frac{dx}{\lfloor x\rfloor}\geq\int_{n}^{n^2+1}\frac{dx}{x}\geq\int_{n}^{n^2}\frac{dx}{x}=\log n. $$

Answer (score 3):

Your idea is absolutely correct, just some details are wrong.

For $t\ge k$ we have $\frac1 t \le \frac1k$. So $$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1}\frac1k \ge \sum_{k=n}^{n^2-1} \int_{k}^{k+1} \frac1tdt = \int_n^{n^2} \frac1tdt = \ln n.$$ Hence $$\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \frac1k \ge \ln n +\frac1{n^2},$$
which tends to infinity as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: Thanks a lot but you are starting from $n^2+1$ instead of $n^2$

Comment: And I meant to end at $n^2-1$ instead so the integral is pretty.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

$\tiny{An\ option:}$

$\tiny{\sum_0=\dfrac{1}{n}}$.

$\tiny{\sum_1= \dfrac{1}{n+1}+....+\dfrac{1}{2n} \gt
n\dfrac{1}{2n}}$.

$\tiny {\sum_2= \dfrac{1}{2n+1} +\dfrac{1}{2n+2} +.. \dfrac{1}{3n} \gt n\dfrac{1}{3n}}$.

$\tiny {\sum_{n-1}= \dfrac{1}{(n-1)n+1}+.....\dfrac{1}{(n-1)n +2}+.....+}$

$\tiny{\dfrac{1}{n(n-1)+n} \gt n\dfrac{1}{n^2}}.$

$\tiny{Combining:}$

$\tiny {\sum_{k=n}^{n^2} \dfrac{1}{k}=\sum_{0}+\sum_{1}....+ \sum_{n-1} \gt}$

$\tiny{ 1/n +(1/2+1/3 +1/4+.....1/n )}$.

Comment: Thanks, I'm grateful!

Comment: Michael.A pleasure! Greetings.